# Old printer keeps showing up

Tags: 20.04, printing

Years ago, I had an old laserjet.  I haven't used it in years.  Nevertheless, it keeps showing up on my newly installed ubuntu along with my new printer.  Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Under settings/printers tap the cog wheel for that printer. There you will find an option to remove it.

Comment: Thank you, but I've done that over and over,  It disappears, but then comes right back.  It's very odd.  I don't know if it's a cups issue or a security issue or what it is.

Comment: One thing that's so strange is this is a clean install that's a month or so old, and I haven't used that printer in years.

Comment: Weird. Maybe it hasn't been removed from all the machines on your LAN. Do you have a Win machine there maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what happened.  Cheers.

Comment: I have a raspberry pi that was once a print server.  I shudder at the thought of Windows. ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Both that you managed and the shuddering :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I figured this out.  I have a raspberry pi dns server that has cups installed, and I never removed this printer from cups on that server.  In fact, I'd forgotten that the pi had been a print server.  So I did

```
sudo lpstat -s
sudo lpadmin -x printername
```

Now the printer is gone.  I will probably remove cups next from the pi.  Thanks for your help.